# Позиционирование меню при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Вот HTML

```
<div class="flex">
    <a href="#" class="chart_tab"><span>30 дней</span><span data-tab-dropdownmenu = "tab_menu_1" class="dropdown_btn_3"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="tab_menu" data-dropdownmenu = "tab_menu_1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">10 дней</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">20 дней</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">30 дней</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">40 дней</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Вот CSS

```
.dropdown_btn_3 {
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 9px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.chart_tab .dropdown_btn_3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 15px;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    z-index: 3;
}

.tab_menu {
    display: none;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

.tab_menu.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

Вот JQuery

```
$("[data-tab-dropdownmenu]").on("mouseover", function() {
    menu = $("[data-dropdownmenu = '"+$(this).attr("data-tab-dropdownmenu")+"']");
    topCoord = $(this).offset().top + 12;
    leftCoord = $(this).offset().left - 70;
    menu.addClass("visible");
    menu.offset({top: topCoord, left: leftCoord});
});

$("[data-tab-dropdownmenu]").on("mouseleave", function() {
    menu = $("[data-dropdownmenu = '"+$(this).attr("data-tab-dropdownmenu")+"']");
    leftCoord = -$(window).width()*2;
    menu.offset({left: leftCoord});
    menu.removeClass("visible");
});
```

Контейнер .flex имеет определенную высоту и она меньше чем высота меню .tab_menu. Контейнер .flex имеет свойство overflow:hidden.
Поэтому нужно при наведении на .dropdown_btn_3 это меню спозиционировать и убрать его только при уведении курсора от .dropdown_btn_3 и .chart_tab. Также если курсор на меню .tab_menu, то меню тоже не должно убираться.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Добавил в JS

```
$("[data-dropdownmenu]").on("mouseover", function() {
    menuName = $(this).attr("data-dropdownmenu");
    btn = $("[data-tab-dropdownmenu = '"+menuName+"']");
    topCoord = btn.offset().top + 12;
    leftCoord = btn.offset().left - 70;
    $(this).addClass("visible");
    $(this).offset({top: topCoord, left: leftCoord});
});

$("[data-dropdownmenu]").on("mouseleave", function() {
    menuName = $(this).attr("data-dropdownmenu");
    leftCoord = btn.offset().left - 70;
    leftCoord = -$(window).width()*2;
    $(this).offset({left: leftCoord});
    $(this).removeClass("visible");
});
```